# Uploading Model from Blender to SketchFab Problem

Tags: texturing

[image]
Hi. I am having this problem with SketchFab whenever I try to upload 
the model from Blender 3d.

This is what shows up in SketchFab site while

[image]
this was the output that I was hoping to see.

As you see, they both looked different. I am also confused, what went wrong with the potion and handle of the sword? It won't appear in SketchFab. Please bear with me as I am quite new in Blender. Thank you so much.